# removeFromSuperview doesn't work properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, view

In class

```
@interface StartScene : UIView
```

I call an instance of

```
@interface HelpView : UIView {
    GameOverMenu* gorm;
    PlayScene* tView;
}
```

and use `addSubview`. I also got huge code here

```
-(void) removemyself {
    [tView removeFromSuperview];
    [gorm removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)restartPlay {
    [tView removeFromSuperview];
    [self playSceneDidLoad];
}

-(void)gameOverDidLoad {
    [tView removeFromSuperview];
    gorm = [[GameOverMenu alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];
    gorm.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGround.jpg"]];
    [gorm checkScore:Scores];
    [self addSubview:gorm];
}

-(void)playSceneDidLoad {
    [gorm removeFromSuperview];
    tView = [[PlayScene alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 520)];
    tView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGround.jpg"]];
    [self addSubview:tView];
    [tView ooneFingerTwoTaps];
}
```

And two sub classes of `HelpView`:

```
@interface PlayScene : HelpView

@interface GameOverMenu : HelpView <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

In `StartScene` when I push on a button, an instance of `HelpView` is created and in init method `playSceneDidLoad` is called.

Inside the `PlayScene` there is restart button which calls `restartPlay` method. When game is lost `gameOverDidLoad` method is called.

And In both `PlayScene` and `GameOverMenu` there are quit button, which calls `removemyself` method, that are supposed to return player to the main menu.

At first glance it should work fine, but if I press restart button for several times and than try to press Quit, it occurs that the views were not removed from superview, one press on a quit button only now removes them one by one. 
And we stop on the HelpView, it didn't remove itself (even if I try to call `[super removeFromSuperview];` somewhere.

I need to remove views correctly in time and to get to the main menu (StartScene) when quit is pressed. I don't think that a lot of views covering each other is a good variant. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I occurs that the point is that if super class' method is called from the subclass and there is such a command `[self removeFromSuperview];` or `[(someOtherSubview) removeFromSuperview];`, it is subclass that uses self or (someOtherSubview). If our subclass doesn't have the pointed subView, than the command would do nothing. And if there is `[self removeFromSubview];`, subclass would remove itself.

Actually I solved this problem by using buttons as subView of superclass.